# Why are Pty and Overall Progress displaying HTML instead of traffic light and progress bar

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online

With our sharepoint setup at the moment, everybody apart from 2 users are seeing the traffic light system for pty, and are also seeing a progress bar. But there are two users who are getting the HTML displayed out instead. i have uploaded a picture to illustrate the problem: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/21/78pd.jpg/?sa=0

does anybody know how to fix this problem or what is causing it in the first place?

Comment: first thought: IE10.

Comment: tested in ie9, 10, chrome, firefox and safari, all the same, nothing to do with the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like [text to html calculated columns](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/using-calculated-columns-to-write-html/), is that correct? If so, have all the scripts and resources been checked in, published as a major version and approved? Are the only 2 people who see it correctly users with full control provs?